# Picking out specific values from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame that I have created from a json url. It has two columns, bpi and time. The bpi values are dictionaries for the first three rows and the time values are NaN. The last three rows are NaN for bpi and timedate values for time. I would like to return row 3, column 1, and row 4 column 2. The complicated part is that from row 3, column 1- I would like to select only specific key, value pairs from the dictionary. How can I do this?

```
[in] print(btc)
[out]
                                                          bpi  \
EUR         {'code': 'EUR', 'symbol': '&euro;', 'rate': '3...   
GBP         {'code': 'GBP', 'symbol': '&pound;', 'rate': '...   
USD         {'code': 'USD', 'symbol': '&#36;', 'rate': '4,...   
updated                                                   NaN   
updatedISO                                                NaN   
updateduk                                                 NaN   

                                 time  
EUR                               NaN  
GBP                               NaN  
USD                               NaN  
updated     Aug 27, 2017 14:07:00 UTC  
updatedISO  2017-08-27T14:07:00+00:00  
updateduk   Aug 27, 2017 at 15:07 BST
```

I only want `rate` from the USD dictionary, plus the `updated` value from the `time` column.

The output should be one row for every date value- followed by a column that lists `rate`s

Here is the output when the df is modified using pandas `.to_dict`

```
[in]
btc_dict = btc.to_dict()

print(btc_dict)
[out]
{'bpi': {'EUR': {'code': 'EUR', 'symbol': '&euro;', 'rate': '3,671.8281', 'description': 'Euro', 'rate_float': 3671.8281}, 'GBP': {'code': 'GBP', 'symbol': '&pound;', 'rate': '3,397.8616', 'description': 'British Pound Sterling', 'rate_float': 3397.8616}, 'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'symbol': '&#36;', 'rate': '4,378.8400', 'description': 'United States Dollar', 'rate_float': 4378.84}, 'updated': nan, 'updatedISO': nan, 'updateduk': nan}, 'time': {'EUR': nan, 'GBP': nan, 'USD': nan, 'updated': 'Aug 27, 2017 14:07:00 UTC', 'updatedISO': '2017-08-27T14:07:00+00:00', 'updateduk': 'Aug 27, 2017 at 15:07 BST'}}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell how you would like your output to look like

Comment: Ok, i added the desired output format- I was unable to show an actual description of what it should look like though.

Comment: Can you please print `df.to_dict()` and paste it here? Your data is not copy-paste friendly and we can't work with it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I edited my question to include the output when the dataframe is transformed using `dt.to_dict()`

Comment: Can you explain how you want these values to look like in an output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my desired output is a csv with two columns, `btc_price`(USD) and `time`- your posted answer was working. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @zsad512 Because I wanted to make sure my answer was right before keeping it alive. So, you want a CSV with two columns, but only one row?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that is correct, one row- also....i would like to update the csv every time the url is called instead of overwriting the previous values (if you can help with this also that would be awesome)

Comment: @zsad512 Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could just use `df.loc` and access these values, like so:

```
r = df.loc['USD', 'bpi']['rate']
y = df.loc['updated', 'time']

df = pd.DataFrame({'btc_price (USD)': [r], 'time' : [y]}) 
print(df)

  btc_price (USD)                       time
0      4,378.8400  Aug 27, 2017 14:07:00 UTC
```

To save to CSV, you'd use `df.to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

---

If you must append to the same dataframe in future, you'd first create a new dataframe and append to your existing CSV file:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([[new_rate, new_time]], columns=['btc_price (USD)', 'time'])
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    df_new.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Comment: How can I then put these values into a list or dictionary? My goal is to start with an initial recording and then add a new row to a csv everytime the url request is called

Comment: @zsad512 Edited.

Comment: Thank you @COLDSPEED but still- this lacks one important feature. What I would like to do is create a csv file that is being updated with new values constantly, without having the old values overwritten....is there not a convenient way to do this? I will eventually be programming the script to run automatically every minute and the csv should grow each time... however, the json file i am pulling from will always produce only one row

Comment: @zsad512 I mentioned how you can append to the csv as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best is create new columns from `dict`s:

```
d = {'bpi': {'EUR': {'code': 'EUR', 'symbol': '&euro;', 'rate': '3,671.8281', 'description': 'Euro', 'rate_float': 3671.8281}, 'GBP': {'code': 'GBP', 'symbol': '&pound;', 'rate': '3,397.8616', 'description': 'British Pound Sterling', 'rate_float': 3397.8616}, 'USD': {'code': 'USD', 'symbol': '&#36;', 'rate': '4,378.8400', 'description': 'United States Dollar', 'rate_float': 4378.84}, 'updated': np.nan, 'updatedISO': np.nan, 'updateduk': np.nan}, 'time': {'EUR': np.nan, 'GBP': np.nan, 'USD': np.nan, 'updated': 'Aug 27, 2017 14:07:00 UTC', 'updatedISO': '2017-08-27T14:07:00+00:00', 'updateduk': 'Aug 27, 2017 at 15:07 BST'}}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#replace NaNs to {}
df['bpi'] = df['bpi'].fillna(pd.Series([{}], index=df.index))

#new df by constructor, join column time last
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['bpi'].values.tolist(), index=df.index).join(df['time'])
#convert rate column to float 
df1['rate'] = df1['rate'].replace(',','',regex=True).astype(float)
#convert time column to datetimes
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
print (df1)
           code             description       rate  rate_float   symbol  \
EUR         EUR                    Euro  3671.8281   3671.8281   &euro;   
GBP         GBP  British Pound Sterling  3397.8616   3397.8616  &pound;   
USD         USD    United States Dollar  4378.8400   4378.8400    &#36;   
updated     NaN                     NaN        NaN         NaN      NaN   
updatedISO  NaN                     NaN        NaN         NaN      NaN   
updateduk   NaN                     NaN        NaN         NaN      NaN   

                          time  
EUR                        NaT  
GBP                        NaT  
USD                        NaT  
updated    2017-08-27 14:07:00  
updatedISO 2017-08-27 14:07:00  
updateduk  2017-08-27 15:07:00
```

Or use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) like in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43228551/2901002) with your original json data if possible:

```
df = json_normalize(d)
print (df)
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#sample
df3 = df1[(df1['code'] == 'EUR') & (df1['rate'] > 1000)]
print (df3)
    code description       rate  rate_float  symbol time
EUR  EUR        Euro  3671.8281   3671.8281  &euro;  NaT
```